# where we can find Dataflow - Advanced Profiles option in magento2?

Tags: magento2, profiler

Dataflow - Advanced Profiles

Dataflow - Profiles

I want  to import product using profiler in magento2

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's remove from M2.

Comment: Have any other way to use advanced option for product import  in magento2

Answer (score 1):

Not without using extensions. There is quite a lot of useful information here https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-product-import-export.html about importing and exporting in Magento 2 and some suggested plugins if the out the box options do not suit your needs! Hope it helps!